# Index and css won't work on public_html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to CSS Html and JS. I'm trying to set up my homepage, though when I upload the html and css...it won't load. Instead I get a list of folders or the files i've been working on.
If you click the html, that is what I want it to show when the page is loaded...tried tutorials, and they won't work.
I'm using filezilla and Brackets.
thanks!

http://people.ucsc.edu/~vmarti21/

Comment: Use lower case, linux file system is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have specified otherwise in .htaccess or in another config file, the default webpage is index.html not Index.html.

Answer (score 0):

You should not capitalize Index.html. It should instead be index.html, try that.